# Customize the auto update functionality for chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, auto-update, self-hosting

So i am working in a chrome extension which won't be hosted on the google webstore, thus i will need to add the auto-update functionality to it, however i need it to be a little more dynamic, i will try to illustrate what i am trying to accomplish by a little scenario so it won't seem pointless.

**Scenario**

I need to have an extension that's kinda have different editions for each version, i.e. each version have a free edition and a paid (feature rich) edition, and whenever a new version is released the extension will be updated according to it's edition.

In other words, the server should be able detect the user's edition and provide the crx file according to it "i.e. dynamic".

**What i tried / think of**

1.I tried to set a cookie with the extension edition, so when the auto-update occurs the server can check it and generate the xml file, unfortunately i found that cookies don't get sent in the auto-update headers sent by chrome.

2.I can make the extension talk to the serve when chrome start-up, so it will send it's edition, so the server will store it along with the ip and when the auto-update occurs the server will check the request ip and match it with the edition to provide the xml, i think this could work but it's kinda lame method.

3.I can use native apps to modify the manifest file to point to a different xml file according to the edition, i guess this will work too but i am not in favor of using native apps.

4.I tried to find a way to modify the get-request parameters (i.e. to add custom parameters like the edition), but it seems that there is no way to do so.

5.I can separate different editions to be different extensions (i.e. free edition will be a in different package than the paid one), however i am interested to make it all in one, so the user can upgrade/downgrade their subscription without installing/removing the extension they already have.

I guess that's it and i hope some one would have a better idea on how i can accomplish what i am trying to do.

***P.S.*** I know the title is kinda vague but i couldn't find a better one, so if you came up with better title please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the free edition version `1.*` and the paid edition version `2.*`?  Then make your update page generated dynamically by a simple PHP page, that gets the app id and version (see the [autoupdate docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html#H2-4)).

Put `"update":"http://www.mysite.com/update_app.php` in your manifest.  In your PHP script, read `$_GET['version']`, and serve an XML update document to match the major version number (`1.*` free version, `2.*` paid version).  Basically, keep two XML update files on your server (and two CRX files) and have the script decide which one to serve.

It doesn't have to be PHP, of course; any server-side language will do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
But what if the user wanted to upgrade/downgrade his subscription ?!
Any ideas how this can be implemented ?!


I am trying to make the things easier for the user when he decides to change his subscription by automating the up/down grade part instead of bugging him with dealing with two extensions or re-installing them, i think your approach will enable me to successfully merge the two editions but the user won't be able to change his subscription, am i right or did i miss something on your approach?!